# OnPropertyChanged and instance property

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

i have a WPF window called Layer_Properties, a WPF window called MainWindow and a MapViewModel.
in the MapViewModel i create an object<Layer_Properties> and i want to observe any changes of a Layer_Properties property called Stops_List in order to refresh a treeview in MainWindow.xaml

class Layer_Properties

```
public partial class Layer_Properties : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Properties
    
    public MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;


    private ObservableCollection<Stop> _Stops_List = new ObservableCollection<Stop>();

    public ObservableCollection<Stop> Stops_List   // property
    {
        get { return _Stops_List; }   // get method
        set { _Stops_List = value; }  // set method
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

class MapViewModel

```
public class MapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MapViewModel()
    {
        _activeLayerProperties = new Layer_Properties();
        _numberOfStops= _activeLayerProperties.Stops_List.Count;
    }

    private Map _map;
    public MapView _mapView;
    public MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    private ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties> layersPool = new ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties>();
    public ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties> LayersPool
    {
        get { return layersPool; }
        set
        {
            layersPool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LayersPool));
        }
    }

    private Layer_Properties _activeLayerProperties;
    public Layer_Properties activeLayerProperties
    {
        get { return _activeLayerProperties; }
        set
        {
            _activeLayerProperties = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(activeLayerProperties.Stops_List));
        }
    }

    private int _numberOfStops;
    public int numberOfStops
    {
        get { return _numberOfStops; }
        set
        {
            _numberOfStops = value;
            if(_numberOfStops >0)
            {
               //Refresh treeview
            } 
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="MapViewModel.PropertyChanged" /> event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var propertyChangedHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedHandler != null)
            propertyChangedHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The logic is as follows;
add all Layer_Properties instances to an ObservableCollection<Layer_Properties> LayersPool.

Copy layer_Properties instance to a _mapViewModel.activeLayerProperties in order to know what is the active instance.

Refresh the treeview everytime Stops_List.Count changes. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: And what is the question? Additionally if you have `[CallerMemberName]` in `OnPropertyChanged` implementation, you may call `OnPropertyChanged()` without any arguments and it will work.