# Name dynamically generated combobox items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am currently working on a WPF project in .NET Core 3.1. During the execution I have to read some file names to a combobox. I do that by first adding them to a list. After that I iterate through that list and add them to the combobox.

*Problem*
Because they should only be accessible if an Item from another combobox is selected, I need to disable the items I just added. Because of that, and to later enable them, I need to name them. But I could not figure our how to do that.

*Here is my code:*

```
        string[] allAircraft;
        allAircraft = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\ApplicationName\Aircraft\", "*.lxml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var currentAircraft in allAircraft)
        {
            aircraft.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentAircraft));
        }

        foreach (string currentListItem in aircraft)
        {
            comboAircraft.Items.Add(currentListItem);
        }

        foreach (ComboBoxItem currentComboItems in comboAircraft.Items)
        {
            currentComboItems.Name = "comboAircraftItems" + currentComboItems.Content;
        }
```

At the line `foreach (ComboBoxItem currentItems in comboAircraft.Items)` I get the Exception:

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.'`

I am really running out of ideas. I googled one entire day but could not find anything.

Have a nice day everyone!

Comment: Do you have a multiselect ComboBox? ComboBox usually selects a single item. How do you realize multi select? To enable a disabled an item is there another criteria other than the user selects this item in the primary ComboBox?

Answer (score 2):

@ t-kldw, Your task is very difficult to solve when working directly with UI elements.
But it is very simple to solve, if you separate the Data and their Presentation, as it should be in MVVM.

Unfortunately, what you wrote contains few details for an example with full implementation.
I can give only partial advice.
It is necessary to create an additional container-class for the data needed in one combo box.
This class MUST have an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

To simplify, take implementation from the topic [OnPropertyChanged and instance property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615111/onpropertychanged-and-instance-property/62620664#62620664)

```
/// <summary>Base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.</summary>
public abstract class BaseINPC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>Called AFTER the property value changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.
    /// In the property setter, the parameter is not specified. </param>
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

An example class with two properties: File Name and IsEnabled to allow selection.

```
public class FileItem : BaseINPC
{
    private string _fileName;
    private bool _isEnabled;

    public string FileName { get => _fileName; set { _fileName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    public bool IsEnabled { get => _isEnabled; set { _isEnabled = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

So that I can give further advice, you need to provide more details of your task.
For example, I don’t even have a clue why currentComboItems.Name might be needed ....
I think that you are clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert `String` to `ComboBoxItem`. When you populate your combobox with data, you add `String`, not `ComboBoxItem`. <s>So you should use `String` in the last `foreach` loop.</s>

```
foreach (string currentComboItems in comboAircraft.Items)
{
    currentComboItems.Name = "comboAircraftItems" + currentComboItems;
}
```

Another solution is to add `ComboBoxItem` to your combobox instead of `String`.

```
foreach (string currentListItem in aircraft)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem()
    {
        Content = currentListItem,
        Name = "comboAircraftItems" + currentListItem
    };
    comboAircraft.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: the first option unfortunately does not work. It says that string does not contain a definition for 'Name'.
The second way does not specify a name, right?

Comment: @t-kldw Sorry, I was mistaken. `String` doesn't have `Name` property. You should use the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemsControl.Items` only holds data objects. In order to render this items, each is wrapped into a container e.g., `ComboBoxItem`. These UI containers are generated by a `ItemContainerGenerator`, which is associated with the current `ItemsControl`. The `ItemContainerGenerator` is also responsible to track the mapping between the data item and its UI container.
To obtain the container of an item you use the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
DependencyObject itemContainer = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

Your simplified code becomes:

```
List<string> allAircrafts = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    Path.Combine(
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
      @"\ApplicationName\Aircraft\"),
    "*.lxml",
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
  .ToList();

comboAircraft.ItemsSource = allAircrafts;

foreach (string item in allAircrafts)
{
  var itemContainer = comboAircraft.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;
  itemContainer.Name = "comboAircraftItems" + itemContainer.Content;
}
```

But note, that the approach you chose has issues. When UI virtualization is enabled for `ItemsCopntrol`, then only the visible items have their containers generated. Items out side the viewport of the scroll viewer are not generated and can't be returned by the `ItemContainerGenerator`.
Since UI virtualization is not enabled for the `ComboBox` by default, this still can work, as long you don't enable this performance optimization feature.

The optimal solution would need you to create a filtered source collection for the `ComboBox` that displays the filtered items. This way you won't clutter the control with items that are not of interest for the user and are not selectable anyway.

Create a collection of type `ObservableCollection<string>` which contains the selected items of the primary `ComboBox` you named `comboAircraft`.
Set this collection as `ItemsSource` of the second filtered `ComboBox`.

Alternatively create a `CollectionViewSource` of the original source collection and bind it to the secondary `ComboBox`. `ICollectionView` supports filtering.
The proper solution

Using either of the two recommended solutions eliminates the requirement to care about item containers. This adds flexibility and simplifies your code.